# Get element from object (array) by its class

Tags: javascript

Give me some tips please, I have an object with data - I get it with `parentNode`. Here is my data in the object:

[image: data in the object]

I need to get data of element ul.district-areas. I can do this by its key - 2, but I would like to explicitly indicate that I need an element with a specific class. Is it possible to do this, and if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the Dom List to an array and then find the className as per your Match.

1. Approach for finding only direct child

   ```js
    Array.from(parentNode).filter((dom) => dom.className.contains("district-areas"))
   ```

if You like to find the DOM specifically (ie. ul.district-areas) then add tagName as well

```js
    Array.from(parentNode).filter((dom) => dom.tagName === "UL" && dom.className.contains("district-areas"))
```

2. Approach for finding a Dom which is a Nested-child. From parentNode(parent Dom element) finds the child element which is in any level.

```
parentNode.querySelector('ul.district-areas')
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do check if an element has a class via the `classList` property:

`myElement.classList.contains("this-class")`

In you case, I would filter the array and return only those elements that match the specified classes

`var filteredArray = myArray.filter(function(element){ return element.classList.contains("this-class"); });`

If your "array" is not actually an array and is actually a `HTMLCollection`, then you would need to convert it to an array first:

`myArray = Array.from(myArray)`

Answer (score 1):

you could do the following:

```
Array.from(parentNode).filter(it => it.localName == "ul" && it.className == "district-areas")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript Array.From() to filter out your exact matching see the below screen shots for example

[image: Find/Filter Control From Array]

Answer (score 0):

Just use the function [`querySelector('.district-areas')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector). Prefixing the name with a dot indicate it's a class.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert object to array You can use `Object.values()`

```
Input : var object = { 0: '23', 1: 'geeksforgeeks', 2: 'true' };
        console.log(Object.values(object));
Output : Array ["23", "geeksforgeeks", "true"]
```